# Issue displaying div's side by side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a scrollable div which should show 3 div's side by side.
Below is my html code, Issue with below code is it is not showing 3 div's side by side instead it is displaying one after other.

```
   <div id="myDIV2" class="mygrid-wrapper-div">
        <h1>This is scrollable div </h1>
        <div class="row row-list">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div>
                   Test1
                    </div></div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">Test2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div>
                  Test3
                </div></div> 
        </div></div>
```

css code:

```
 <style>
        .mygrid-wrapper-div {
            /*border: solid red 5px;*/
            overflow: scroll;
            height: 40%;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: I would recommend using the flexbox or grid layout.

Answer (score 1):

A `div` is a "block-level" element. Block-level elements are 100% of the width of their parent element and displayed on their own line by default.

There are several ways to override this layout:

Set `float` for the element, which reduces it's width to the width of the content and allows other elements to be on the same line with the floated element.

Set the width to an amount that leaves left over space for another element to fit on the same line and set the element to be `display:inline` or `display:inline-block`.

Take the element out of the normal document flow by setting its `position` property to `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

Make the elements flexitems within a flex container.

```css
.mygrid-wrapper-div {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 40%;
}

.col-xs-4 { 
  border: 1px solid red; 
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV2" class="mygrid-wrapper-div">
    <h1>This is scrollable div </h1>
    <div class="row row-list">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div ng-controller="myController">
                <div ng-repeat="c in chart">
                    <div google-chart chart="c">test</div>
                </div></div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">22222222 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">  <div ng-controller="myController">
            <div ng-repeat="c1 in chart">
                <div google-chart chart="c1">test</div>
            </div></div></div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: I have applied as you suggested but div3 is not shown after div2 instead it is displaying down. Please find the updated demo where we can see div3 down to div1, any inputs ?
 https://plnkr.co/edit/QVcmTYv59gTF9DEQpejV?p=preview

Comment: @user3692021 are you sure that the widths of all 3 div elements combined doesn’t exceed the width of the container? Even with float, content will still flow to the next line if it can’t fit on the current line.

Comment: Can we overide the width and make all the 3divs fit one after the other ?

Comment: You’d have to place them in a container that was set to a width that is greater than 100%, which will result in the user having to scroll to the right to see the excess. This is not generally a good UI decision.

Answer (score 0):

Add the css style:

```
float:left;
```

to your divs.

Comment: I have included float:left as suggested but didn't worked. Please find the updated demo https://plnkr.co/edit/Vfb1P9O8iwu3pk0gEroI?p=preview @Luke Barrier

Answer (score 0):

Your `plnkr.co` example was not loading `bootstrap`, which is why you were not seeing your divs aligned as expected. Made the following changes to make it work:

Removed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Added:

```
<link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Check https://plnkr.co/edit/r6a7lJpNNG2UI1qDbcb6?p=preview